# onload redirect aleatorio

Tags: javascript, random

Gostaria de criar uma função que carregasse uma página aleatória de um determinado endereço. Algo do tipo `www.meusite.com/(numeros entre 0-100).html`

Acho que a função deveria criar a *tag* `A`, depois preencher com o texto `www.meusite.com/ + random number + .html`; e no final ser ativada por `onload` dentro da *tag* `body`.

Tem como fazer algo do tipo usando JS? Acredito que sim mas nem sei por onde começar.

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"ativada por onload dentro da tag body"_? Queres um redirect automático aleatório? ou clicando num link que tem um endereço aleatório?

Comment: Sem click, gostaria que fosse automatico.

Comment: Percebes as implicações para o utilizador de ir para uma página e ser redirecionado para outra no browser? Isso é mau e os motores de busca não gostam... Não podes fazer esse redirect no servidor?

Comment: Na verdade eu estou tentando criar uma pagina inicial que abra links aleatorios cada vez que eu abra o browser. os links seriam de paginas com mensagens e frazes do dia de um site especifico

Comment: Concordo com o Sergio, em que isso é daquele tipo de paginas que eu evito a todo o custo, em que estou numa página de repente sou magicamente levado para outra à sorte.

Comment: Como disse acima, a pagina em si nao sera publicada, ficara armazenada localmente no meu Pc,sera usada como pagina inicial. apenas os links estarao online. teoricamente concordo que seja bastante irritante, mas nesse caso como o redirecionamento e para uso pessoal nao vejo problema

Comment: Podes fazer isso também exibindo uma seção da página com a informação aleatória. Aí essa página poderia vir como um `iframe` com página aleatória ou definido no servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML insira um onload que chama uma função:

```
 <body onLoad="mudarPagina()">
```

Função JavaScript:

```
 function mudarPagina() {
      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      location.href="http://www.meusite.com/"+random+".html";
 }
```

Seria isso?

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, mais simples que eu imaginava, porem jamais conseguiria sozinho. Muito Obrigado

Comment: De nada, js é bem simples mesmo recomendo que assista vídeos do [rodrigo branas](https://www.youtube.com/user/rodrigobranas) no youtube para saber mais sobre js, angularjs e nodejs

Comment: Vou ver os videos sim, muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica